# Stack TOP pointer is always null

Tags: c

I am creating a new stack using linked list. I dont know why the TOP pointer is always pointing to NULL. I think I am not setting the top pointer correctly, or it is not visible outside the function.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef struct StackItem
{
      int itemValue;
      struct StackItem* NextItemPtr;
}StackItem;

typedef struct Stack
{
    struct StackItem *TOP;
}Stack;

int IsStackEmpty(StackItem *TOP)
{
     if(TOP==NULL)
         return 1;

}

void pushItem(StackItem *headPtr,int n)
{
    StackItem* Newnode;
    Newnode=(StackItem*)malloc(sizeof(StackItem));
    Newnode->itemValue=n;
    printf("Checking Head TOP %d\n\n",IsStackEmpty(headPtr)); //Everytime it is giving 1 
    Newnode->NextItemPtr=IsStackEmpty(headPtr)?NULL:headPtr;
    headPtr=Newnode;
}


int main()
{
   Stack* stackptr;
   stackptr=(Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
   stackptr->TOP=NULL;
   pushItem(stackptr->TOP,3);
   pushItem(stackptr->TOP,6);
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: You're passing your TOP pointer by-value. You should pass it by address.

Comment: Why you people don't learn C before trying to write an OS...

Comment: I can't believe this has been up for 10 minutes and no one has commented yet on the malloc-cast. Durp... nm. so much for that P. Or the system includes with open quotes (`#include "stdio.h"`) rather than angle brackets (`#include <stdio.h>`).

Comment: @H2CO3 I don't think that's relevant at all. The OP isn't trying to write an OS. He's trying to learn C. Where is the problem?

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm too tired to notice that :D Anyways I can hardly read the code given that it *lacks whitespace...* But here, take my upvote for that comment.

Comment: @corsiKa I was being sarcastic. OP is obviously trying to solve a problem for which his programming knowledge hasn't yet grown up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement does nothing for the caller:

```
headPtr=Newnode;
```

You can:

- Pass a double pointer and assign to `*headPtr`
- Return `Newnode` instead of assigning to `headPtr`

This [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html) explains this very subject.

Comment: @WhozCraig I think "This statement does nothing **for the caller**" is clear enough.

Comment: @H2CO3 that would be the 5-min no-history. the initial post did not have "for the caller", but since it does now, Ill drop the comment.

Comment: He could also pass the Stack itself in instead of the stack item.

Answer (score 1):

```
headPtr = Newnode;
```

Since `headPtr` is an argument of the function, it's passed by value. Modifying it inside the function does not have any effect in the caller. You need to pass a pointer to it and modify it through the pointer:

```
void pushItem(StackItem **headPtr, int n)
*headPtr = NewNode;
```